# Maps zooms out on update change

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google maps on my Android Studio. I am trying to make a gps that tracks a user. The problem I have is that every time I move with my my phone, the app zooms out of the map every time the location updates. I don't know why this is happening. Thank you guys!

Here is my code

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality()+",";
                        str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


        }
        else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality()+",";
                        str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `GoogleMap.moveCamera` so it's moving and in `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` you are moving the camera with Zoom. If you don't want Zoom you can use `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng` as you did in `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`

Answer (score 1):

Replace line:

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f))

with:

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));